# camel-kafka rollback not working when kafkaException thrown

Tags: apache-camel, spring-camel

I have a spring-boot application that uses spring camel-kafka-starter in my POM

Java 11
Spring-boot 2.7.13
camel 3.16.0

The flow is:

```java
onException(KafkaException.class)
        .log("Kafka Exception - ${exception} - ${exception.message}")
        .handled(true)
        .markRollbackOnly()
        .end();

from("KafkaUri")
    .transacted()
    .process(MyProcessThatsSavesTheRequestToOracleUsingJPA);
```

In my Process

```java
//Code to map to object 
eventInformationDao.save(dto);
```

1. Kafka message is consumed from the topic
2. Message is mapped to the DTO and saved
3. Kafka consumer goes to commit the offset, but fails as the commit was not done in time and a re-balance was triggered and the consumer was removed from the consumer group CommitFailedException
4. The consumer connects back to the group. The same offset is consumed again, however I can see the row has already been commit to the DB, even though I wanted it rolled back which leads to Oracle exception for duplicate.

I assume the default transactionManager, created by spring, is used end to end, so in the *onException* method I should be able to tell the transaction manager to not commit the message and to rollback?